# Showing Convergence of Sequence from monotone subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My questions is as follows:

Let $(u_n)$ be defined by $u_1=1$ and

$$u_{n+1} = u_n + \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \;\;\;\; \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Show that the subsequence $(u_{2k-1})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is monotone decreasing and that the subsequence $(u_{2k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is monotonic increasing. Conclude from this that the sequence $(u_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is convergent.

---

So far I have:
$$\begin{aligned}
u_{2k-1} &= u_{2k-2} + \frac{(-1)^{2k-2}}{2k-2} \\
&=u_{2k-2} + \frac{1}{2k-2} \\
&=u_{2k-3}  + \frac{(-1)^{2k-3}}{2k-3}+\frac{1}{2k-2} \\
&=u_{2(k-1)-1} -\frac{1}{(2k-3)(2k-2)} \\
u_{2k-1} - u_{2(k-1)-1} &= -\frac{1}{(2k-3)(2k-2)} <0
\end{aligned}$$
Hence $u_{2k-1} < u_{2(k-1)-1}$ and so $(u_{2k-1})$ is decreasing. I used a similar argument to show that $(u_{2k})$ is increasing. I have thought for a while on how to conclude convergence, and one way to go about it would be to show $(u_{n})$ is Cauchy, but I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Any help would be much appreciated. Also please bear in mind I am quite new to analysis, so may have overlooked something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $k$  we have $u_1\geq u_{2k-1}>u_{2k}$ so the increasing sequence $(u_{2k})_k$ is bounded above by $u_1$ so it has a limit $A.$

For any $k$  we have  $u_2\leq u_{2k}<u_{2k+1}$ so the decreasing sequence $(u_{2k+1})_k$ is bounded below by $u_2$ so it has a limit $B.$

We have $A-B=(\lim_{k\to \infty}u_{2k})-(\lim_{k\to \infty}u_{2k+1})=\lim_{k\to \infty}(u_{2k}-u_{2k+1})=0$. Therefore $A=B.$

Given $e>0,$ take $k_1\in \Bbb N$ such that $k\geq k_1\implies |u_{2k}-A|<e$ and take $k_2\in\Bbb N$ such that $k\geq k_2\implies |u_{2k+1}-A|<e.$ Then $n\geq 1+2\max (k_1,k_2)\implies |u_n-A|<e.$

Comment: Considering how the question is asked, this is likely the desired answer. But because of Gentleman_Narwhal's apparent intuition, both approaches seemed worth mentioning.

Comment: @MattAPelto . I'm fine with that.

Comment: Regarding the last part: For any $e>0$ there are only finitely many even $n$ such that $|u_n-A|\geq e$ and only finitely many odd $n$ such that $|u_n-A|\geq e,$ so altogether there are only finitely many $n$ such that $|u_n-A|\geq e.$ Since this holds for every $e>0$, therefore $u_n\to A.$

Answer (score 2):

There are technically two ways to go about proving that the sequence $\{u_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges. Since you say that you are new to analysis, I will note that either argument is perfectly valid as far as you should be concerned. Though it might be to your benefit to notice that the classical argument explicitly invokes a limit which in a more general context we won't be able to know. I say more general context as clearly,
\begin{aligned} \lim_{n \to \infty} u_n &=1 - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}  \\&=1-\log(2). \end{aligned}

- [**Classical:**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2907944/showing-alternating-series-is-convergent-by-definition-with-condition-b-1-b-2/2908273#2908273) Show that the subsequence $\{u_{2n-1}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded below and decreasing. Show that the subsequence $\{u_{2n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded above and increasing. Conclude both subsequences are convergent sequences by the *monotone convergence theorem for sequences* which implies the nonconstructive proposition known as the *limited principle of omniscience*. Conclude both subsequences converge to a common limit.
- **Constructive**: Without loss of generality, suppose $n>m$. You may prove (an exercise left for the reader) via strong induction $(*)$ that for every $n \in \mathbb N$, we have
  $$0 \leq \frac1{m+1}-\frac1{m+2}+\frac1{m+3}-\cdots \pm \frac1{n}\leq \frac1{m+1}\,.
  $$
  Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. By the Archimedean Principle, we may find a positive integer $N$ so that $N>\frac1{\varepsilon}$. So for all $n>m\geq N$, we have
  \begin{aligned} \left|u_n - u_m \right| &= \left|\frac1{m+1}-\frac1{m+2}+\frac1{m+3}-\cdots \pm \frac1{n}\right| \\& \leq \frac1{m+1} \\& < \varepsilon. \end{aligned}Therefore, the sequence $\{u_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence.

$(*)$ **Hint**: There are two cases to consider for the induction step, even and odd.